# set animation for popup items when popup create

Tags: android, animation, popup

I have a layout with only some vertical button which is in linear layout, want to set animation for all button when popup show for example this anime for all button

```
    Animation animation = 
    new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -size, size);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    animation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
```

this code is for create popup

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.popup_buy,
                        (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(
                                R.id.popup_element));
                pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
                pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

and i know i can access to button with this code

```
                Button btn1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_opt1);
```

however how can i set anim for all button when popup create ?

Answer (score 0):

following code is using for set animation to a view

```
btn1 .startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

After try anythings i used from this code,and solved my problem with timer ! :(

```
            pwindo.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopUp_Animation);//OPS : 500 ms
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            final Button btn1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final Timer tm = new Timer();
            tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tm.cancel();
                    anim_list_ anim_list = new anim_list_();

                    float loc1 = btn1.getTop();
                    Animation list_v_anim1 = anim_list.list_v(Height,loc2,50);
                    btn1.startAnimation(list_v_anim1);
                }
            }, 1, 550/*550 here !*/);
```